# move to MKPointAnnotation old let long to new let long with animation

Tags: swift

how can in a `enter code here map-kit move to MKPointAnnotation old let long to new let long with animation with move Move With Effect  in swift

used this code
animation with also draw a polyline

let startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0118, longitude: 72.5055)
let destinationPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0133, longitude: 72.5308)

```
    // Set the region the MapView will be looking at at.
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startPosition, 100000, 100000)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
  
    
    moveDelivery(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0133, longitude: 72.5308))
    
    
    
    allLocations.append(startPosition)
    
    
    
    // Add annotation to map.
    myAnnotation.coordinate = startPosition
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
```

` weak var timer: Timer?
func movePosition() {
// Set timer to run after 5 seconds.

```
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { [self] _ in
            // Set animation to last 4 seconds.



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {                    // Update annotation coordinate to be the destination coordinate
                self.myAnnotation.coordinate = destinationPosition
                
            }, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

//         Start moving annotation.
movePosition()
`

used than MKPointAnnotation Move but I cant draw Polyline parallel in swift

Comment: Hi Welcome on stack overflow. Could you reformat your question to have a proper meaning in English?

Comment: We want to draw a Polyline, whenever we move the MKpointAnnotation between the two different Coordinate Position with Animation